# In adapter calling from native android app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using android studio for developing my android app. SO i created a native API using the worklight 7.1.0 and copied all the jar files to the lib folder and wlclient.properties to the asset folder. So after that i have a set of adapter deployed in my company server, which i have to invoke from native code. So i changed all the values in the wlclient.properties as per the adapter required to call.

I added a listener for the connect and tried connect , it gave a Unexpected error.

I added a listener for invoking the adapter and tried connect, it gave a Application is not found in the server, couldnt register client

Answer (score 0):

You only provided your explanation, and not any real example... so that's not helping to understand the real culprit here.

What I can say is:

1. > So i changed all the values in the wlclient.properties as per the adapter required to call.

   What you put in wlclient.properties is the **server address** for the **client application** to connect to. It does not relate to the adapter per-se. The adapter is invoked by the **server** once a request from the client came in.

   The adapter then sends a request to what that is defined in the `connectionPolicy` element of its {adaptername}.xml file.
2. Various exceptions

   Since you did not provide anything useful that can be debugged - I suggest that you will instead review the following tutorial and its sample application: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/invoking-adapter-procedures-native-android-applications/

   The tutorial mentions the required steps to take in order to use the MobileFirst API in the Android app.

Comment: Do we have to deploy the Native API in the server to use the adapter in that server ?

Comment: Yes. That is how the server then knows about your client. It is like deploying a .wlapp for a Hybrid app; same thing.

Comment: If there is a server which has some adapters, and I have the jar and client.properties from project that i have created locally . I have copied these jar and client.property from the project i have created. And I have changed the ipaddress , port number , context and environment as per the details from the server  which have adapters. Will it work?

Comment: As long as you deploy the app's .wlapp file (available in the bin folder of your local MobileFirst project) to that remote server that contains the adapters, it should work.

Comment: One more thing , when i do WL.client.connect from a native app, i get Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.UNEXPECTED_ERROR error. How can i debug what is the real error?

Comment: There is no such native API. I do not know how you implemented your code; again, see the sample application.

Comment: Sorry made a big mistake, I used client.connect(new MyConnectListener()) call and i got "Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.UNEXPECTED_ERROR ".